# How to create complex filters in Kibana 4?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have Kibana 4 set up and now I want to "hotlink" to some concrete search results in "Discover".

I want something like `(_type:"php_error_log" AND project:my_project) OR (_type:"nginx_error_log" AND project:my_project) OR (_type:"sql_slow_log" AND database:"db_my_project")`. I could use queries, but that is annoying as it highlights the filtered items in the list. Also it would be easier for users to query for the thing they're looking for using the search box while having all the "jibberish" (i.e. other system logs and so) filtered out by the filter.

Is it possible? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

The use case is to hotlink to search results from out internal tools and show aggregated logs from multiple sources related to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to default kibana with a set of filters, but not have them be obvious to your users.

For that, I would suggest that you create a [filtered alias](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered), which will look like a regular index, but it will include your pre-defined filters automatically.

Comment: Not really, they could be obvious to the users. They just need to be filters AND be complex. I could do something like `_type:php_error AND _type:mysql_error`, but not complex like the one I mentioned in question...